# Get data from a json array in PHP

Tags: php, json

I receive a really long json array like following:

```
a:2:{s:18:"_gravity_form_lead";a:227:{s:3:"3.2";s:0:"";s:3:"3.3";s:5:"Name";s:3:"3.4";s:0:"";s:3:"3.6";s:1:"T";s:3:"3.8";s:0:"";i:4;s:14:"123456789-3505";i:6;s:0:"";s:3:"7.1";s:0:"";s:3:"9.2";s:0:"";s:3:"9.3";s:0:"";s:3:"9.4";s:0:"";s:3:"9.6";s:0:"";s:3:"9.8";s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";s:4:"13.1";s:0:"";s:4:"13.2";s:0:"";s:4:"13.3";s:0:"";s:4:"13.4";s:0:"";s:4:"13.5";s:0:"";s:4:"13.6";s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";i:16;s:0:"";i:84;s:0:"";i:85;s:0:"";i:18;s:0:"";i:19;s:0:"";i:20;s:0:"";i:21;s:0:"";i:22;s:0:"";i:88;s:0:"";i:89;s:0:"";i:90;s:0:"";i:91;s:0:"";i:92;s:0:"";i:93;s:0:"";i:94;s:0:"";i:96;s:0:"";i:97;s:0:"";i:98;s:0:"";i:102;s:0:"";i:99;s:0:"";i:100;s:0:"";i:101;s:0:"";i:104;s:0:"";i:105;s:0:"";i:106;s:0:"";i:107;s:0:"";i:108;s:0:"";i:109;s:0:"";i:110;s:0:"";i:112;s:0:"";i:113;s:0:"";i:114;s:0:"";i:115;s:0:"";i:116;s:0:"";i:117;s:0:"";i:118;s:0:"";s:4:"28.1";s:0:"";s:4:"28.2";s:0:"";s:4:"28.3";s:0:"";s:4:"28.4";s:0:"";s:4:"28.5";s:0:"";s:4:"28.6";s:0:"";i:29;s:0:"";i:30;s:0:"";s:4:"33.1";s:0:"";s:4:"33.2";s:0:"";s:4:"33.3";s:0:"";s:4:"33.4";s:0:"";s:4:"33.5";s:0:"";s:4:"33.6";s:0:"";i:35;s:0:"";i:36;s:0:"";i:37;s:0:"";i:38;s:0:"";i:41;s:0:"";s:4:"39.1";s:0:"";s:4:"39.2";s:0:"";s:4:"39.3";s:0:"";s:4:"39.4";s:0:"";s:4:"39.5";s:0:"";s:4:"39.6";s:0:"";i:121;s:0:"";i:122;s:0:"";i:123;s:0:"";i:124;s:0:"";i:126;s:0:"";s:5:"125.1";s:0:"";s:5:"125.2";s:0:"";s:5:"125.3";s:0:"";s:5:"125.4";s:0:"";s:5:"125.5";s:0:"";s:5:"125.6";s:0:"";i:128;s:0:"";i:129;s:0:"";i:130;s:0:"";i:131;s:0:"";i:132;s:0:"";s:5:"133.1";s:0:"";s:5:"133.2";s:0:"";s:5:"133.3";s:0:"";s:5:"133.4";s:0:"";s:5:"133.5";s:0:"";s:5:"133.6";s:0:"";i:135;s:0:"";i:136;s:0:"";i:137;s:0:"";i:138;s:0:"";i:139;s:0:"";s:5:"140.1";s:0:"";s:5:"140.2";s:0:"";s:5:"140.3";s:0:"";s:5:"140.4";s:0:"";s:5:"140.5";s:0:"";s:5:"140.6";s:0:"";i:142;s:0:"";i:143;s:0:"";i:144;s:0:"";i:145;s:0:"";i:146;s:0:"";i:149;s:0:"";i:150;s:0:"";i:151;s:0:"";i:152;s:0:"";i:153;s:0:"";s:5:"147.1";s:0:"";s:5:"147.2";s:0:"";s:5:"147.3";s:0:"";s:5:"147.4";s:0:"";s:5:"147.5";s:0:"";s:5:"147.6";s:0:"";i:155;s:0:"";i:156;s:0:"";i:157;s:0:"";i:158;s:0:"";i:159;s:0:"";s:5:"160.1";s:0:"";s:5:"160.2";s:0:"";s:5:"160.3";s:0:"";s:5:"160.4";s:0:"";s:5:"160.5";s:0:"";s:5:"160.6";s:0:"";i:162;s:0:"";i:163;s:0:"";i:164;s:0:"";i:165;s:0:"";i:166;s:0:"";s:5:"167.1";s:0:"";s:5:"167.2";s:0:"";s:5:"167.3";s:0:"";s:5:"167.4";s:0:"";s:5:"167.5";s:0:"";s:5:"167.6";s:0:"";i:169;s:0:"";i:170;s:0:"";i:171;s:0:"";i:172;s:0:"";i:173;s:0:"";s:5:"174.1";s:0:"";s:5:"174.2";s:0:"";s:5:"174.3";s:0:"";s:5:"174.4";s:0:"";s:5:"174.5";s:0:"";s:5:"174.6";s:0:"";i:176;s:0:"";i:177;s:0:"";i:178;s:0:"";i:179;s:0:"";i:180;s:0:"";s:5:"181.1";s:0:"";s:5:"181.2";s:0:"";s:5:"181.3";s:0:"";s:5:"181.4";s:0:"";s:5:"181.5";s:0:"";s:5:"181.6";s:0:"";i:40;s:0:"";i:43;s:2:"Ne";i:184;s:0:"";i:185;s:0:"";i:48;s:0:"";i:187;s:0:"";i:188;s:0:"";i:189;s:0:"";i:191;s:0:"";i:192;s:0:"";i:193;s:0:"";i:195;s:0:"";i:196;s:0:"";i:197;s:0:"";i:199;s:0:"";i:200;s:0:"";i:201;s:0:"";i:44;s:0:"";i:45;s:0:"";i:50;s:2:"Ne";i:51;s:2:"Ne";i:52;s:2:"Ne";i:53;s:0:"";i:55;s:0:"";i:56;s:0:"";i:57;s:0:"";i:58;s:0:"";i:59;s:0:"";i:60;s:2:"Ne";i:61;s:2:"Ne";i:62;s:0:"";i:69;s:2:"Ne";i:70;s:0:"";i:71;s:0:"";i:72;s:0:"";i:77;s:0:"";i:78;s:0:"";i:79;s:0:"";i:80;s:0:"";i:81;s:0:"";i:203;s:0:"";i:204;s:27:"56f26f5862fb85.90873638.png";}s:18:"_gravity_form_data";a:14:{s:2:"id";s:1:"1";s:13:"display_title";b:0;s:19:"display_description";b:0;s:25:"disable_woocommerce_price";s:3:"yes";s:12:"price_before";s:0:"";s:11:"price_after";s:0:"";s:20:"disable_calculations";s:3:"yes";s:22:"disable_label_subtotal";s:3:"yes";s:21:"disable_label_options";s:2:"no";s:19:"disable_label_total";s:3:"yes";s:14:"disable_anchor";s:2:"no";s:14:"label_subtotal";s:8:"Subtotal";s:13:"label_options";s:7:"Options";s:11:"label_total";s:5:"Total";}}
```

I need to extract the name of the `png` which in this array is: `56f26f5862fb85.90873638.png`. The value is the following context:
`i:204;s:27:"56f26f5862fb85.90873638.png";`

It would be really convenient if I could look the name after the `204` which is always fixec.

Any guidance or suggestion as for how to solve it is much appreciated.

Comment: I think it's a serialized object rather than JSON because as a JSON it's invalid.

Comment: What you get is a serialized array, not JSON. `unserialize` it.

Comment: Its not a valid JSON..check here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Its a serialized array so in order to use it you must use `unserialize` method.

Answer (score 0):

That is a serialized PHP value, created using the [`serialize()`](http://php.net/serialize) function.

You can unserialize it using the [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize) function:

```
 $data = unserialize('a:2:{s:18:"_gravity [...] tal";s:5:"Total";}}');
```